# XML format of USPTO patent

Tags: format, xml

What are the various fields in patent XML file.
For example: does 'detailed description' have a separate field?

Comment: What patent information database are you looking in?

Comment: need to retrieve xml's of USPTO patents belonging to a specific classification only. Found the xml format OK, but wonder if there is something ready available out there.